# Profile Location module - output full Country Name

Tags: drupal

Can anyone tell me how to output the full country and state names using the Profile Location module?  (Drupal 6)

Currently, it will just spit out WA, US for Washington, United States.

The author says that he has added hook_profile_alter to display country and state long string values on user view page, but I'm not sure how to implement this.

Can someone help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this function into your [custom module](http://drupal.org/developing/modules):

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_profile_alter().
 */
function CUSTOMMODULENAME_profile_alter(&$account) {
  $profile = user_load($account->uid);
  $category = variable_get('profile_location_category', NULL);
  $country = variable_get('profile_location_country', NULL);
  $state = variable_get('profile_location_state', NULL);
  if ($state) {
    $account->content[$category][$state]['#value'] = profile_location_get_state($profile->$country, $account->content[$category][$state]['#value']); // Here you can check state names.
  }
  if ($country) {
    $account->content[$category][$country]['#value'] = profile_location_get_country($account->content[$category][$country]['#value']); // Here you can check country names.
  }
}


  [1]: http://drupal.org/developing/modules
```